# Tag excerpt shown twice when searching for user and tag

Tags: bug, design, search, tag-excerpt

When using both a user and a tag in search, the tag excerpt is shown twice:

[image]

This happens on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1+%5Bc%23%5D). Not on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1+%5Bdiscussion%5D), [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1+%5Bdiscussion%5D) or [SU](https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A1+%5Bwindows%5D).

Looking at the other pages, the tag excerpt above the `x results` and `Relevance, Newest, More` buttons shouldn't be there.

Comment: It also happens with other search options. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Belementtree%5D+is%3Aanswer

Comment: Yes, it seems like all you have to do is search for a tag and anything else but it only happens when there's only one tag. Multiple tag searches work as expected: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Belementtree%5D+is%3Aanswer+%5Bpython%5D